# Location of socket() function implementation in linux

Tags: linux, sockets

In Linux, to create a socket we include the sys/socket.h header file and use the socket() function. The header file is located at /usr/include/sys/socket.h.

```
extern int socket (int __domain, int __type, int __protocol) __THROW;
```

Can anyone please tell the location where the socket() function is actually implemented.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acutally, 
`int socket (int __domain, int __type, int __protocol) __THROW`

implemented in glibc,

and the glibc  calls the kernel function sys_socket implemented in kernel file [net/socket.c](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/net/socket.c?v=2.6.25.8).

```
asmlinkage long sys_socket(int family, int type, int protocol);
```

Answer (score 2):

[socket(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/socket.2.html) is a [ssytem call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call). The `socket` function inside *Glibc* is just a tiny wrapper to make the real system call.

From an application's point of view, system calls are *atomic*; in other words, the virtual machine on which your Linux application program is running is the *x86* machine (the non-priviledged instruction set) augmented with the more than 300 system calls provided by the kernel. See also [Assembly Howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/) which explains how a system call can be coded. Read more about the [linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) and the [syscalls(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [intro(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/intro.2.html) man page.

The real work about sockets is done inside the kernel, it is the networking subsystem.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is => [socket.c](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=socket/socket.c;h=273924a05c2beae4df1fbba415593fcb9be70272;hb=HEAD).

Usually most of the socket functions, including this one, are just wrappers around system calls (direct calls to the kernel), hence it is all handled by the almighty kernel itself.

Here is the Kernel's implementation: [SYSCALL_DEFINE3(socket, int, family, int, type, int, protocol){...}](http://www.koders.com/c/fid40497F7C1025CC6DC835CC1627C1910C44264CB9.aspx?s=%22sys_socket%22#L1266)

Comment: The `socket.c` you pointed to is *not* the right one. This one is (32-bit version): http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/socket.S